# OpenRAVE IKFast scipy error

Tags: ros, urdf, inverse-kinematics, ikfast, openrave

I'm attempting to use the python app [pyikfast](https://github.com/cyberbotics/pyikfast) to generate an analytic solution to my 6 DOF arm. I was able to successfully run the pyikfast solver on the PUMA 560 arm so I know the solver *can* work. It uses a Docker image to run IKFast solver on my arm's URDF file and create a python binding with the solution. When trying to run the docker run command on my URDF file, pyikfast starts doing computations on my arm. After a couple of minutes I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/domains/pythonrationalfield.py", line 34, in from_sympy
    raise CoercionFailed("expected `Rational` object, got %s" % a)
sympy.polys.polyerrors.CoercionFailed: expected `Rational` object, got -oo
```

This error message always gets thrown after this line of output:

```
openravepy.ikfast: SolveAllEquations, depth=2 c=34, [j0, j1, j2, j4, j5] [j3]: cases=set([Abs(j4 + atan2(new_r02, 50000455212072161441*new_r12/455212072161441)), Abs(new_r00) + Abs(new_r02)])
```

I have tried tweaking the parameters in my URDF file however I keep getting the same error at, seemingly, the same line of code. Any ideas on how to proceed? I believe the source code for the IKFast solver is [here](http://openrave.org/docs/latest_stable/_modules/openravepy/ikfast/).